# Angular - Refresh array list after a new object being pushed

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, array-push

I am currently trying to figure out how to automatically refresh the ngFor list when a new object has been pushed to the array.
Currently I have the following

component.html

```
    export class HomePage implements OnInit { 
  collections: Collection[];
  public show = true;
  constructor(){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.collections = this.collectionList;
  }

  _collections: Collection[] = [
      new Collection('i1', 'Range Rover', 'Model 2019'),
      new Collection('i2', 'Lancer Evolution', 'Model 2008')
    ]

  get collectionList() {
      return [...this._collections];
  }

  addItem(){
    this.testAdd();
  }

  testAdd(){
      this._collections.push(new Collection('i3', 'Chevrolet Camaro', 'Model 2020'));
  }
```

component.ts

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-col *ngFor="let col of collections;">
    <div>{{col.title}}</div>
    <div>{{col.description}}</div>
  </ion-col>
  <div style="padding-top:10px;">
        <button type="submit" class="label-center" (click)="addItem()">Add new item</button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Here's the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-wjtvvv?embed=1&file=pages/home/home.ts)

What am I actually missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment of `_collections` variable to the `collections` variable happens only once during `ngOnInit`.

Pushing a new value to `_collections` array, makes no difference in the `collections` array, as its a different copy of the original array and not a referenced version of `_collections`.

To achieve the expected outcome make the following change:

```
testAdd(){
      this.collections.push(new Collection('i3', 'Chevrolet Camaro', 'Model 2020'));
  }
```

**Alternate approach** :

Using the spread operator returns a new array. If you want to create a reference between `_collections` array and `collectins` array then update the get function to

```
 get collectionList() {
      return this._collections;
  }
```

Comment: well I overlooked it. Thank you for your explanation